# Single Sign On Using cURL With Third Party API

Tags: php, curl

Alright, I have done my best to get this far using the answers here prior to posting.  I am trying to execute a single sign on (SSO) from between a Wordpress Membership Site using Membermouse and a third party content provider.

The third party requires that the following information be posted to a specific URL via these instructions on their API documentation:

"Primary Login URL: https://pumpone.com/api/v1/******

Parameters:

api_key

api_secret

email

user_id - this is the user's id in your system"

I have have put together the following php (if you can call it that, I am very new to all coding):

```
<?php

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$settings = array();
$settings["api_key"] = "768749b4f42104f9d*************";
$settings["api_secret"] = "5ade7bb55bbf4ebcc5**********";
$settings["email"] = "$current_user_email";
$settings["user_id"] = "$current_user_id";

$url = "https://pumpone.com/api/v1/*******";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $settings);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

To display the third party content on my webpage I am required to use the following:

```
<div id="fitnessbuilder-private-label-embed">
<script>
<!-- embed with your api key -->
fitnessBuilderPrivateLabel.embed_sso('768749b*************', 'SESSION_KEY');
</script>
</div>
```

Where the 'SESSION_KEY' must be dynamically inserted into the page.

I am struggling to dynamically insert the SESSION_KEY within the PHP, and to be honest, I am not sure that I am even on the right track with the PHP as I am very new to this.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: When does SESSION_KEY get generated?

Comment: Straight from the API documentation:"SESSION_KEY is the value returned from the SSO login API call. This value will have to be dynamically inserted into the HTML template and will be unique for each user."